# How to get user id from a replyed message? (telebot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

I want a create a bot that add or leave "points". For do this i use for every user a single txt file nominated with they id.
For add points i wanna do a replyed message with `/addkarma (number of points)`  and i want add karma (the points) at the user who i replyed the message **(karma=points)**.
How i do it? Everytime i do `print(message.reply_to_message.json.from.id)` for check what bot take from this, python give me a error like this

```
print(message.reply_to_message.json.from.id)
                                    ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

please help

```
import telebot
import os



bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

def newuser(points,id):
    with open(f"{id}.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(points)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['addkarma'])
def user(username,points,message):
        file = os.path.exists(f'/users/{id}.txt')
        if not file:
            newuser(points,id)
        id = message.reply_to_message.json.from.id
        file_name = os.path.basename(f'/users/{id}.txt')
```

thats all my code and what i try to do

ps.Is my first post here, not really good to write english and wanna help, please forgive me for eng errors. Also pretty new to telegram bots :)

Comment: You might be using an attribute to access a dictionary value - from a quick look at github, might it be `...reply_to_message.from_user.id`?

Comment: usually in Python, json data is stored as a `dict` and is addressed like this: `blahaj.json()["from"]["id"]` - unless whoever wrote `blahaj` did some extra work

Comment: Sorry, what mean "access to the dictionary value" i know basic of python never user dictionary value or else, can you explain to me better?

Comment: Python dictionaries: `kallax = {"billy": 42, "lack": 123}`. here `kallax` is a dictionary, and `billy` and `lack` are its keys. You get the values with `kallax["billy"]` (== 42). I think in Javascript you'd write `kallax.billy` to get the 42.

Comment: i try this right now but give me some error, so this remain i need get the user id of the replyed message